# Skimage rgb2gray reduces one dimension

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to convert multiple RGB images to grayscale. However, I am loosing one dimension

```
# img is an array of 10 images of 32x32 dimensions in RGB
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
print(img.shape) # (10, 32, 32, 3)
img1 = rgb2gray(img)
print(img.shape) # (10, 32, 3)
```

As you can see, though the shape of img is expected to be (10, 32, 32, 1), it is coming out as (10, 32, 3).

What point am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [function](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#rgb2gray) assumes the input to be one single image of dims 3 or 4 (with alpha).

(As your input has 4 dimensions, it's interpreted as single image of RGB + Alpha; not as N images of 3 dimensions)

If you got multiple images you will need to loop somehow, like this (untested):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
print(img.shape) # (10, 32, 32, 3)

img_resized = np.stack([rgb2gray(img[i]) for i in range(img.shape[0])])
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I feed only one 3-d image and I get one 2-d image. This is the example shapes: 3x224x224 to 3x224!